# When CComCriticalSection::Lock may return E_FAIL

Tags: c++, com, atl

MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04tsf4b5.aspx) says:

> Return Value
>
> Returns S_OK on success, E_OUTOFMEMORY or E_FAIL on
>   failure.

What failure might be with acquiring lock?

Comment: Just guessing, failure to call `.Init()` (or `.Init()` failing) or use after calling `.Term()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it'll never return that. The references to `E_FAIL` and `E_OUTOFMEMORY` are likely standard comments wherever methods return an `HRESULT`. This method likely returns an `HRESULT` for consistency with other methods and/or compatibility with other ATL classes.

Here is the code for `CComCriticalSection` in the vc140 (2017) toolset. Previous toolsets back to vc90 (2008) have similarly simple `Lock()` methods. The only changes between 2008 and 2017 were the addition of the [SAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx) attributes `_Success_` and `_Acquires_lock_`, which have no functional impact (they expand to nothing). I cannot comment for toolsets prior to 2008.

```
class CComCriticalSection
{
public:
    CComCriticalSection() throw()
    {
        memset(&m_sec, 0, sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION));
    }

    ~CComCriticalSection()
    {
    }

    _Success_(1) _Acquires_lock_(this->m_sec) HRESULT Lock() throw()
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_sec);
        return S_OK;
    }
    _Success_(1) _Releases_lock_(this->m_sec) HRESULT Unlock() throw()
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_sec);
        return S_OK;
    }
    HRESULT Init() throw()
    {
        HRESULT hRes = S_OK;
        if (!_AtlInitializeCriticalSectionEx(&m_sec, 0, 0))
        {
            hRes = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }

        return hRes;
    }

    HRESULT Term() throw()
    {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&m_sec);
        return S_OK;
    }
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_sec;
};
```

Comment: I am under impression that previous versions of ATL converted certain exceptions to `E_FAIL` (`__try` and friends). This should have been removed at some point.

Comment: In vc90 (2008), there is a `__try` around the `InitializeCriticalSection()` in `Init()`, but the `Lock()` doesn't have any SEH.

Comment: Later versions tweak `Init()`, but `Lock()` and `Unlock()` haven't changed since 2008 at least, other than the addition of the SAL annotations.

Comment: I could have confused with `Init`, indeed. Another reason why they could have wanted to do a `HRESULT` function, which never returns a failure, is that other "compatible" classes exist and they are all expected to work with other templates like `CComCritSecLock`. Just because some other implementation, even supposed, could return a failure code, they made all classes have `HRESULT` return type. But you are correct here - the documentation has a standard stub that a caller is rather to examine the returned status code.

Comment: Agreed on the consistency point. It may also be simply so that all methods in this class return `HRESULT`, another point for consistency.